# Overlay onTap not working after Android Back button?

Tags: android, overlay

I have several Overlays drawn on a MapView with ItemizedOverlay, and an onTap that works when I first start my app.  However, if I press the Back button on the Android then start my app again the onTap does not work at all.  Other touch sensative operations work fine, like long press on the map and several face buttons.  It is also fine if I press the Home button on the phone then go back into my app, so its only on the Back button.  It will also work if I first open another app like the Maps app, then go back into my app, acting like a reset.

Overriding the onBackPressed method to move the task to the background also does not work, does anyone have any ideas what would cause this?  It happens in both the emulator and on a real device.

I don't know if it will help but here is the relevent code:

```
public OverlayManager(MapsTest launcher)
 { 
  m_mapView = (MapView)m_activity.findViewById(R.id.mapview);

  // init the list to the mapview list and clear it out
  m_overlayList = m_mapView.getOverlays();
  m_overlayList.clear();

  // create an overlay list for each overlay type
  for( OverlayTypes o : OverlayTypes.values() )
  {
   m_itemOverlay[o.ordinal()] = new OverlayList(m_context.getResources().getDrawable(OverlayData.getInstance().getDrawableID(o)));
  }

  // init the SMS sender
  m_smsSender = new SMSSender();

  m_mapMenu = new MapMenu(launcher, this);
  m_overlayList.add(m_mapMenu);
  m_mapView.invalidate();
 }


public class OverlayList extends ItemizedOverlay<MapOverlayItem>
{
 private ArrayList<MapOverlayItem> m_items = new ArrayList<MapOverlayItem>();

 private int m_lastSelectedItem = 0;

 public OverlayList(Drawable d)
 {
  super(d);
 }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index)
    {
     if( !ProgramState.getInstance().recentStateChange() )
     {
         m_lastSelectedItem = index;
         OverlayData.getInstance().setLastSelectedType(m_items.get(index).getMarkerType());

         InfoBalloon.show(m_items.get(index));
     }

     return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem was actually I had a static Layout being drawn on the onTap method that was just not showing up because it was static (InfoBalloon).  I don't know why, it was going into the draw method and everything, but when I made it not static it works fine!